# Passing data from Capacitor plugin to AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an Ionic Capacitor app, and I have some data within custom capacitor plugin that I need to get into AppDelegate.swift (./ios/App/AppDelegate.swift). How can I call a method in AppDelegate.swift from within the plugin swift code?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function of the app delegate instance using the following pattern:

```swift
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.test()
        }
```

`AppDelegate` must be the name of the delegate class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this today... do you know if there s a similar pattern to pass data from a plugin to MainApplication.java on the android side?

Comment: It appears that when the plugin is built, "npm run verify" fails on account of the "test" method not being visible to the plugin.

Comment: i.e., "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'test'" when trying to build the plugin (outside of the main application where the AppDelegate.swift lives)

Comment: `test` is just a method you need to implement in the app delegate class.